# Code novice, mysql_fetch_array to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been looking to convert some older PHP queries to newer PDO method.

This is where I am at:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dbName = XXXXXXXXX
$dbUser = XXXXXXXXX;
$dbPass = XXXXXXXXX;
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=XXXXXXXXX", $dbUser, 
$dbPass);
$delimiter = "**";
$query = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `portfolio_id` = 'X' AND `image_status` = 'X' ORDER BY rand()";
$conn->query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $sVal = substr($row['image_full'],0); 
    $nString = $nString.$delimiter.$sVal;
}
```

Seems like it is going okay till I get to the "mysql_fetch_array" part.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `mysql_` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use `mysqli_` instead.

Comment: Oh, wait, you're trying to mix mysql_ and PDO.

Comment: @difster, I am not trying to mix them.  I am just showing what I am doing and where it seems to be going wrong.

Comment: Right, but if you start with PDO, you need to keep using it.

Comment: True.  That is what I am trying to do.  I had this working for quite sometime using old php coding I got working, server updated their php and everything broke, so I am trying to convert my old code to newer syntax.

Comment: you shouldnt be using: mysql_fetch_array($query) if you're intending on using PDO

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at these pages it should get you on the right track http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Updated bit:

```
foreach ($conn->query($query) as $row) {
 $sVal = substr($row['image_full'],0); 
$nString = $nString.$delimiter.$sVal;
}
```

With pdo you can iterate through a successful query like this.

Comment: Tried this but I get a PHP fatal error line 30, which is the $result... line  <br/>$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);<br/>

Comment: I've updated my answer. Have a look and that should hopefully get you close.

Comment: thanks that worked perfect.  the foreach vs. while seemed to make all the difference.  I really appreciate the help.  Cheers

Comment: No problem. If you could accept the answer that would be cool :)

Answer (score -1):

You currently pass a string to `mysql_fetch_array`.
Try this:

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted my code as you recommended, but I am getting this in my error log - mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/mobile/iphone.php on line 31

Answer (score -1):

This did the trick:

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```